# Printing off the first element in a array

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm not sure why I get a segment fault when I try to see what index teacher.first is printing.
I used strcpy to place the string Adam in an array of type char, thats in a struct. But i'm not sure why its giving me a segment fault when I try to see what's at index 0.

My assumptions:

- Segment Fault accrue when we haven't allocated enough memory.
  -strcpy(teacher.first, "Adam");  places the string Adam at index 0 of the char/string array that given 32 bytes of memory, when declared at the beginning of the program.
  Possibilities:
- strcpy(teacher.first, "Adam");  places the string Adam separately into the array and index 0 should not be "Adam" but should be A.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person { /*  p e r s o n  i s name f o r s t r u c t u r e t y p e */
  char first[32]; /* f i r s t f i e l d o f s t r u c t u r e i s a r r a y o f
                     c h a r */
  char last[32]; /* s e c o n d f i e l d i s a r r a y o f c h a r */
  int year;      /* t h i r d f i e l d i s i n t */
  double ppg;    /* f o u r t h f i e l d i s d o u b l e */
}; /* e n d i n g ; means end o f s t r u c t u r e t y p e d e f i n i t i o n */

void printperson(struct person personinstance) {
  printf("Printing struct person properties : \n");
  printf("First and last name : %s %s.\n", personinstance.first,
         personinstance.last);
  printf("Year:%d.\n", personinstance.year);
  printf(" Points per game : %lf .\n", personinstance.ppg);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct person teacher;
  int i;
  teacher.year = 2005;
  teacher.ppg = 10.4;
  strcpy(teacher.first, "Adam");
  strcpy(teacher.last, "Hoover");
  /*Why'd I get a segment fault. You get segment faults when you're trying to
  access memory
  that doesn't exist. **/
  // Segment fault:  --> printf("first element of teacher first is: %s\n",
  // teacher.first[0]);
  // Whats at the first index of the array?
  printperson(teacher);
  printf("\n");
  printf("first element of teacher first is: %s\n", teacher.first[0]);
}
```

Comment: The compiler does not care about formatting (mostly), but your code is quite hard for a human to read.

Comment: Your program looks correct (if we ignore the formatting) and behaves as expected on [ideone](https://ideone.com/hyie0W). What are your tools? OS? compiler? compilation options?

Comment: The program compiles and executes here.

Comment: Because I commented it out. I'll edit the code so that it breaks and gives a segment fault.

Comment: You mean the *comment-out code* `printf("first element of teacher first is: %s\n", teacher.first[0]);` causes a segfault? That is because `teacher.first[0]` is not the address of the string.

Comment: So I changed the print statement to %c and that fixed it. I made the mistake of assuming a Strings and Chars are the same thing.  Thanks, guys!

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure what you mean by teacher.first[0] is not the address of the string, "Adam."

Comment: `teacher.first[0]` is `'A'`, the first character of the string, and passing that where an address is expected, will likely cause a segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you suggest that this line of code is causing the segmentation fault:

```
printf("first element of teacher first is: %s\n", teacher.first[0]);
```

The format specifier `%s` expects a c-string as the argument, not a single character. To print a single character use `%c`.

#### As an aside...

If your compiler is not complaining about this, please get a newer compiler to help you notice these errors. For example, clang-7 reports:

```
main.c:31:53: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but
      the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
  ...of teacher first is: %s\n", teacher.first[0]);
                          ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          %c
```

Comment: Welp that fixed it. Thanks

Comment: So basically when I use strcpy(teacher.first, "Adam"); Thats just a 1-row array that has 32 bits of memory. And when I assign Adam to that memory I use up 4 bytes of that memory.

Comment: @PlayerUnknown_12 Almost; It's an array of 32 __bytes__ of memory. Copying Adam into it uses __five__ bytes, there's an additional one for a `\0` character denoting the end of the string.

Comment: So now I'm thinking and wondering why %s  didn't work. I mean, isn't "A" considered a string?

Comment: Note the error that clang reported. `char` is different from `char *`.